# Will Upgrading an RFS6000 from 4.3 to wing 5

Tags: switch, ieee-802.11

I was just wondering if upgrading an RFS 6000 from 4.3 to Wing would wipe the configuration that is already set up the RFS, i've looked around online but cant seem to find anything.

Comment: I'm curious if you found an answer to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Went ahead with the firmware upgrade and it did wipe the configuration as it is an entirely different OS.